# Why Rotor use MSCOREE?

Tags: sscli

I Built SSCLI 2.0 From Source. Then I Was Wrote A Simple C# Program.
Then I  build Program With CSS.exe Inside The ROTOR Output Folder.
When I Dump Imports From this Executable with dump bin I Still Seeing  _CoreEXEMain From mscoree.
and if I run exe without Clix.exe , CLR Loads And Executes Program Not SSCLI.
Why The Executable Does not use sscoree?
If We Don't Have .Net Framework, We cant use SSCLI?
thanks

Comment: If you want something to play with, use .NET Core CoreCLR.

Comment: @LexLi what about dependency on mscoree? why my executable links with mscoree?

Comment: Nobody cares about a toy when the actual runtime is now open sourced.

Comment: @LexLi why Microsoft created .Net Core ? Why he Doesn't write new PAL for other platforms? What if in a few years he releases .Net Core Core and mark .Net Core as a deprecated toy? what about many lines of our codes?

Comment: Not sure what led you to Rotor, but its source code was released by Microsoft as a reference when .NET Framework was not open sourced and people would like to learn a little bit about the internals. That’s why it was a toy from day 1. .NET Core has been open sourced from it’s very beginning, so there was no room for Rotor since then. An open source project can rarely go deprecated, as if you like you can maintain it.